# Dividing 4 teachers into 3 rooms with condition of on room has to hold 2 teachers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have test that is being held in 3 rooms `A B C` , and we have 4 teaches `P Q R S`. Each teacher has to be supervision in one room. The condition is that one room will have 2 teaches as supervision and no room can remain without supervision.

We are to find the number of ways how to divide teachers inside room.

If we didnt have condition. We would just divide 4 teachers into 3 rooms which is basic combination =

$\binom{n }{ k}$ = $\binom{4}{3}$ = $\binom{4!}{(4-3)!*3!}$ = 4

But how to solve  it with this condition?
I really appreciate all explanation and help! Thanks

// edit

since the order should matter here , the amount od combinations dividing 4 teachers into 3 room should be 4 * 3 * 2

Comment: Imagine that the teachers are pigeons?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to choose the room to which two teachers are sent.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two of the four teachers to assign to that room.  There are $2!$ ways to assign the remaining teachers to the remaining rooms.  Thus, the number of ways of assigning the teachers to the rooms so that exactly one room is assigned two teachers is 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2!$$

Answer (score 1):

First select three teachers out of given 4. Then send them in the three classes, one in each class, the last teacher can then be sent in any of the three classes.

The mathematical equivalent of the above procedure would be:

[(4 C 3) × (3!) × 3]/2 = 36.         (Ans.)

The division by two since you can perform the two given actions (sending three teachers first and then sending the last teacher) in any order.

Comment: the answer should be 36

Comment: as i wrote , the correct answer to this should be 36. This is from solved exercises from my school. Answer is 36 but i cannot find out why.

Comment: Its correct now...corrected couple of minor errors.

Comment: Why did you use 4 C 3 ? By sending 3 teachers into 3 rooms its 3! since order does matter here , and then the last one can be send in any of those room so * 3  but how did u got 4 C 3?

Comment: (4 C 3) for selecting three teachers out of given 4.

Comment: Then why using another 3!  ? Its either take 3 teachers and put them into 3 rooms , if order matte =   3! if not its combination 3C3 = 1 . Or am i understanding it completly wrong?

Comment: You can understand it like this: there are four distinct balls and three distinct boxes... first choose any 3 out of 4 given balls... since each box should have one ball... now put these three balls in the given three boxes in 3! ways and then put the last ball in any of the three boxes. Now since you can perform the above two actions in any order... divide the answer by two.